# How to add Google Calendar to a Django Webapp which is already using Django-allauth google social login

Tags: django, google-calendar-api

I am trying to add a google calendar to my webpage for a user who has logged into the website using a google account via the Django-allauth package social login. I have set up the social login, and I am able to login and authenticate users.

Next step will be to add a calendar to the webpage, since I have already logged in with a google account to my website. How do I go about adding a google calendar?